# How to add Right side padding to Horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add the right side padding to the horizontal scroll to make sure the last item in the scroll comes in the center of the screen.

Following is what I am trying! although the left padding work perfectly, I don't understand why right padding is not being applied

```
.option-widget {
 display: flex !important;
 overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 40% !important;
  padding-right: 40% !important;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div className="option-widget">
<IconButton id={selected} className="icon-font" ><img style={{ width: '70px' }} src={image.selected} alt="name" /> </IconButton>
<IconButton id={selected} className="icon-font" ><img style={{ width: '70px' }} src={image.selected} alt="name" /> </IconButton>
<IconButton id={selected} className="icon-font" ><img style={{ width: '70px' }} src={image.selected} alt="name" /> </IconButton>
<IconButton id={selected} className="icon-font" ><img style={{ width: '70px' }} src={image.selected} alt="name" /> </IconButton>
<IconButton id={selected} className="icon-font" ><img style={{ width: '70px' }} src={image.selected} alt="name" /> </IconButton>
<IconButton id={selected} className="icon-font" ><img style={{ width: '70px' }} src={image.selected} alt="name" /> </IconButton>
</div>
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add html too ?

Comment: @SameerKhan Hey, I have added Html too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL;DR**
>   Add `padding-right` to last child element using `element:last-child` (**Example below**)

```css
.option-widget {
  display: flex !important;
  overflow: auto;
}

.icon-font {
   margin: 0 1rem; 
}

.icon-font:last-child {
  padding-right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="option-widget">
  <div class="icon-font">
    <img style="width: 70px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon-font">
    <img style="width: 70px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon-font">
    <img style="width: 70px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon-font">
    <img style="width: 70px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon-font">
    <img style="width: 70px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon-font">
    <img style="width: 70px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon-font">
    <img style="width: 70px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I think you are using some framework to dynamically add images, So I created a simple example with plain `html`.

**I have added `padding-right` as `50%` because `50%` is a half/center of full width which is in total `100%`.**